# What is the name of this "twisted" solid?

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

One of my students asked me about the name of this solid:

[image]

It's kind of twisted triangular prism with convex edges, the base is almost a Reuleaux Triangle with rounded corners. Any ideas?

Comment: @MorganRodgers Well, we two (my student and I) are now wondering, if there is a name for this solid.

Comment: Umm... Twisted rounded prism?

Comment: It’s a tennis trophy. I saw Novak Djokovic holding one like that.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork ...with rounded edges and non-flat faces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your prism-like figure like this?  [click on figure]

[image]

Comment: Almost! The bottom base needs to be rotated counterclockwise a little bit. Is there are name for this solid?

Comment: I deleted my code, but it would be a very minor tweak to rotate the base a bit.  No name for this figure that I know of... but frankly I don't think it has such special properties that it deserves a name.

Answer (score -1):

I have done a great number of these types of things (two animations below) but have never known them to have a particular name. In my 3D programs it's called as swirl.

[image: Swirl animation]
[image: Rotating Swirl]